# Python:converting list to a column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in which one column has a list of values like below.

```
ID     Source
1      [apple,mango]
2      [grapes]
```

Now I am trying to eliminate the list of values in my dataframe and create a new dataframe like below:

```
ID     Source
1      apple
1      mango
2      grapes
```

I am trying to achieve the above with the below code:

```
duplicates = pd.DataFrame()
for _, row in file_df.iterrows(): # file_df is the original dataframe with list of values
        leng = len(row.Source_sentences)
            for j in row.Source_sentences:
                itr = [row.ID,j]
                df2 = pd.DataFrame(row.ID, j, columns=["ID","Source"])
                print(itr)
                duplicates.append(df2,ignore_index=True) 
                idx = idx +1 
    print(duplicates)
```

I am getting the below error

```
TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, 'Apple.' wa
s passed
```

Can someone point me where I am going wrong with the code

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

Input:

```
df = {'ID': [1, 2],'Source': [["apple","mango"], ["grapes"]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
   ID          Source
0   1  [apple, mango]
1   2        [grapes]

df1 = (df['Source'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x))
        .stack()
        .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .to_frame('Source')
        .join(df[['ID']], how='left')
)
```

Output:

```
   Source  ID
0   apple   1
0   mango   1
1  grapes   2
```